# Can you disable automatic memories?

Tags: pc, the-sims-3

I have recently been playing sims 3 including all expansions so far. Generations has memories, which is great, except that everything seems to be a memory. Every time the game come up with a memory, I just click on the close button. For some reason, it gets added to my scrap book. I like the memories that I add to it, but it takes forever to delete the unwanted memories, because you need to delete them one at a time.

Is there anyway to keep from having this problem, such as a disable button?

Comment: *"Yay!"* at unwanted features being included as parts of bug-fix patches. I'm sorry, but I liked my sims better when they didn't have breast or body hair sliders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something i forgot: no you can't turn them off.

check this: http://crinrict-help.blogspot.com/2011/06/tutorial-turn-off-memory-notifications.html

in short go to the options screen: pick the wheels symbol (third symbol from left).
on the left side is a enable memories checkbox notification(or disable it).

Comment: Could you please include the instructions on the link in your answer? We try to encourage this due to the possibility of link rot. :)

Comment: oh yeah once sec